# MVC4 string concat with HTML.DisplayFor and string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to concat a string in MVC

This is what I'm trying to do

```
<img src="~/Content/CompanyLogo/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyLogo)+".jpg"" />
```

But it isn't allowed...

What should I be doing? I am the designer and I don't have the option to edit the model to provide it in the correct format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<img src="~/Content/CompanyLogo/@(Model.CompanyLogo).jpg" />
```

Assuming `CompanyLogo` is a property of your model,Razor will render the value of your CompanyLogo property when the view is rendered.

Note that i used `@()` syntax. The parenthesis syntax explicitly tells razor that it is an expression to be evaluated.

[Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) is a handy list of razor syntax reference, written by Phil

If it is in a for each loop, try this

```
@foreach (var img in Model.Images)
{
  <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/CompanyLogo/"+img.CompanyLogo+".jpg")"/>
}
```

or a more simplified version (`~` works from ASP.NET MVC4 onwards only)

```
@foreach (var img in Model.Images)
{
  <img src="~/Content/CompanyLogo/@(img.CompanyLogo).jpg""/>
}
```

Comment: It won't accept @ Model, only @item as it's part of a foreach loop. using @ item.CompanyLogo.jpg produces a compiler error

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `DisplayFor` in this case. Try this (assuming your `CompanyLogo` is a string property directly on the model):

```
<img src="~/Content/CompanyLogo/" + @Model.CompanyLogo + ".jpg" />
```

Comment: It renders it verbatum

Comment: Sorry, I can't +1 with my rep